# Is there a reason for not allowing a Review Badge to be earned multiple times on the same queue?

Tags: discussion

I've earned the Gold review badge over on SF for reviewing 1,000 close votes already.

I can see that the review badges are only awarded once:

[image]

Is there a good reason for not allowing these badges to be awarded more than once per review queue?  What harm is there in encouraging an additional fake internet award to be earned?

Comment: If you're in it for the badges, then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @bluefeet motive is irrelevant to the question at hand...otherwise badges wouldn't exist at all.  Nor would rep.

Comment: *What harm is there*. Where you here at all when the robo-reviewers were giving us so much pain?! We rather have people do reviews because they care about the quality of the site. It is fine if that's not for you.

Comment: @TheCleaner: the badges exist to encourage the behaviour, not to be the sole reason you do it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I'm not posing this as a feature-request.  I'm asking what the reason is.  If the reason is robo-reviewers that reason is more null and void at this point.  I'm curious what the reasoning behind it TODAY is.

Comment: @TheCleaner: No, the robo reviewers are still here. The audits make it harder now, but moderators still have to manually deal with edit reviewers approving outright spam and vandalism, just because they are not really paying attention, for example.

Comment: @TheCleaner Well, those three badges you earn once both existed before the review system, and are kind of global anyway.  You don't need to use the review queues to get them, but reviewing may or probably will help your progress to badges for editing, voting and flagging, which is probably why they show up in the review system.

Comment: @HopelessN00b: I think TheCleaner is mostly talking about the Steward badges.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - so the badge earning is across all SE sites statically?  If SO has an issue with robo-reviewers but SF doesn't can it be changed per site or no?  I'm just curious.  We have a fairly small dedicated base of experts on SF that even use the review queue.

Comment: @TheCleaner: right, but clearly those reviewers are motivated by other things than earning badges. I see some [stellar review counts](http://serverfault.com/review/close/stats) over on SF.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - true, and I'm right up there with those experts and converse with them all daily.  My question wasn't "what motivates you to review".  It was just "why not allow them to be earned more than once"?  If the answer is "robo-reviewers" then so be it, and someone should post that as the answer to upvote and accept.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You *can* earn all of the review badges multiple times.

...Just not for the same queue.

The goal here is to reward specific achievements that set you apart from other reviewers. Someone with 1 review badge has reached a milestone in handling one specific type of task; someone with 6 review badges has reached that same milestone in several *different* types of tasks.

Allowing the badge to be earned multiple times for the same queue would dilute that meaning.

On a more philosophical note, I tend to dislike multi-award badges for doing essentially the same thing over and over again. They're useful in giving folks a goal to reach for, something to help motivate a whole lot of tedium... But once that goal is reached, it's time to make a decision: are you doing this because you want another badge, or because you honestly believe that *it's a good thing to do?* At some point, **if there's no intrinsic motivation to continue then you should just stop**; doing something for the wrong reason is worse than not doing it at all.

Comment: While a good answer to the title/scope of the question, the part about *"They're useful in giving folks a goal to reach for, something to help motivate a whole lot of tedium... But once that goal is reached, it's time to make a decision: **are you doing this because you want another badge**, or because you honestly believe that it's a good thing to do?"* -- makes an assumption that the original motivation is to get the badge while robo-reviewing which is often not the case.  Most reviewers do so for the right reason, site upkeep...while earning something on the site in the process.

Comment: "roboreviewer" is a pejorative term used for folks who don't review the way you wish they would, @TheCleaner - lots of folks find badges motivating without being *solely* motivated by them, just as plenty of people like seeing their reputation increase without being here primarily for that purpose. Making necessary tasks into a game is all well and good, as long as folks remember that it's not *just* a game.

Comment: Yeah, I'm stating that you might be better worded instead of saying *"But once that goal is reached, it's time to make a decision: are you doing this because you want another badge..."* to something like *"But while reaching that badge, you have to decide: are you doing this because you want a badge, or because you honestly believe that it's a good thing to do?"* -- changes your words to probably better reflect what you want to say.  As it stands it looks like you are saying the original reason to review is to earn the badge and eventually you decide to do it because it is right.

Answer (score 6):

If the badges could be earned multiple times then we'd never be rid of the reviewers only in it for the badge, that aren't here to provide quality contributions and help out the site.  As it is having to deal with a full 1,000 low quality reviews from someone before they finally get their badge and leave is bad enough.  Having to deal with even more, or worse, a never ending stream of low quality reviews from people only interested in more badges would make the system just that much less helpful.

Comment: So honestly your answer should start as "On SO...".  I don't frequent SO so I don't see this issue.  It isn't prevalent on SF.  But if the review badge settings are global SE and not per site, then I can understand not wanting to change it for the sake of SO.  Thank you.

Comment: @TheCleaner Nothing about this is specific to SO.  If someone is reviewing just for the sake of the badges, and wouldn't be reviewing without them, then the quality of their contributions tends to be radically lower.  If there are SF users that wouldn't be reviewing without the badges, then you'd likely be better off without those users.  If there simply *aren't* users reviewing just to get the badges (or not enough to worry about) then this wouldn't change a thing.  So the change would either be negative, or pointless.  There's no site for which it would be *positive*.

Comment: Nobody that actively reviews on SF, myself included, does it solely for the badges.  My comments in my original question above were tongue-in-cheek.  So while I get the need to discourage it on SO, it's not a prevalent issue on SF.  There are 2301 users on SO with the steward badge and less than 10K rep.  On SF there are 29.

Comment: @TheCleaner Meaning that there won't be a ton of users abusing reviews just to get a badge, but then there won't be any change at all.  By succeeding in showing that people aren't reviewing for the badge, you've merely shown that there would be no reason to implement this at all.  Why would they go out of their way to add a new feature that will accomplish nothing?

Comment: I was merely asking what harm there was in allowing it multiple times.  Not what it would accomplish to allow it.  Adding badges period is a fake reward, regardless of what it is.   It's internet fodder.  So while I get the answer you gave, it doesn't mean that suddenly allowing it on SF would cause an influx to the review queue there of robo-reviewers that have already earned the Steward badge there.  If anything, there it would simply be another "thanks" offered up.

Comment: ...But since it appears these review badges aren't site specific, the point stands that the negative impact it would have on SO is enough to keep it as is.

Comment: @TheCleaner The change would have one result.  It will add more bad reviewers.  On some sites it may a very small number (possibly even zero) and on some sites it could be a large number.  Either way, the change is causing some amount of harm, and zero benefit.  This change wouldn't even be worth pushing out on SF alone.  Your **best case** is wasting your time on the feature.  It's not just not done because of SO; it's not done because it's a change that can *only* cause harm, on *any* site.

Comment: BTW +1...I still like your answer.  Don't take my back and forth as negative banter but rather trying to understand the full intent.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Servy when he says:

> we'd never be rid of the reviewers only in it for the badge

Well, i can see folks every day and every time doing things only for badges, and unfortunately this is a normal behaviour.

By the way, the proposal of a badge consists in encouraging people to do good things, and this cannot be forgotten, so maybe a new way to encourage people that already reached this badge, would be useful.

But allowing people to award the same badge more than once per review queue is not a solution to this.